# How to divide a string to a charecter wise?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am having a string @"sairam".
I need a characters separately and i need to store it into an ARRAY like

```
array = [@"s",@"a",@"i",@"r",@"a",@"m"];
```

how to do this give a loop like if i give a string it needs to divide charecters and store it into an array ...

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/Strings/split.html:

```
  NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[myString length]];
  for (int i=0; i < [myString length]; i++) {
      NSString *ichar  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [myString characterAtIndex:i]];
      [characters addObject:ichar];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i=0; i<[passonString length]; i++) 
    {

            unichar tempString=[passon_phoneNumber characterAtIndex:i];
           [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",tempString];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in following way:
Steps :
1. First convert the `NSString` to `cString` using `cStringUsingEncoding`.
2. Then iterate the `cString` and convert back each char to `NSString` if you require.

Answer (score 0):

```
unichar c[string.length];
    char b;
    NSRange range={0,string.length};
    [<string> getCharacters:c range:range];
    printf("%c%c",c[0],c[1]);
```

i used this myself as it gave me a manageable character array  you can see this [link as well](http://codefriends.blogspot.in/2012/05/how-to-extract-character-from-nsstring.html) you can creatively use this character array as u wish